# regex to take string C from {A|B|C}

Tags: regex

Is there any regex master that can help me?

I have a list of words like **{first|second|third}**, and I want just the last word, in this case {first|second|**third**}.

Can anyone help me please??

**Edit**:

After feedback I am adding more information.

I have a sentence such as "I am going to France {today|tomorrow|next week}" for example. But I want only "I am going to France **next week**".

I tried `(?<=\{).*?(?=\|.*?\})` but this gives me `|tomorrow|next week`, I just want `next week` without the vertical lines.

**PS** it doesn't necessarily have to 3 words, I just want the last regardless.

Comment: -1: This question does not show any research effort. What have you tried?

Comment: Read this and improve your question: [John Skeets: Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and [Matt Gemmells: What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I modified the question, is this good enough?

Comment: @happygilmore - This question is better than your previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is obviously:

```
((\w|\s)+)\}
```

Comment: @happygilmore - `[\s\w]+(?=\})` should give you the same result without needing to extract a group.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Sure. Still, I am advocating to come up with the simplest regex possible, and later refine it. For example, make the inner group non-capturing or replace by character class, as you advocate. Whether one wants a lookahead assertion if one can do without one is a matter of taste - I for my part avoid it unless it is absolutly needed.

Comment: @Ingo - I agree that it's essentially the same as your answer (which I upvoted) and that the differences are a matter of taste, not substance. Just providing a similar alternative.

Answer (score 0):

A python test of the regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = """ds like {first|second|third}, and I want just t"""
>>> re.findall('\|([^\|]+)\}', test)
['third']
```

Answer (score 0):

To generally replace `{a|bc|def}` with `def` with no nesting or other complications, search for the regex

```
\{[}]+\|([^|}]+)\}
```

and substitute with the first (and only) parenthesized subgroup. In Perl, that would be something like

```
s/\{[}]+\|([^|}]+)\}/$1/g;
```

Many other languages have a similar syntax, though it might be less compact. In PHP, look for `preg_replace`.

The expression looks complex, but isn't really; we look for a literal `{` followed by the longest possible string of characters which are not `}`, as long as it's followed by a literal `|` and (subgroup) a string of characters which are neither `|` nor `}`, and finally, after the subgroup, a literal `}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/\{.+?([^|]+?)\}/
```

(you can easily test it by typing the following in your browser's JS console)

```
"{first|second|third}".replace( /\{.+?([^|]+?)\}/, "$1")
```

or even

```
"I am going on the {first|second|third}".replace(/\{.+?([^|]+?)\}/, "$1")
-> "I am going on the third"
```